# There is no NF_REJECT verdict in libnetfilter_queue

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, iptables, netfilter

libnetfilter_queue seems to support only two verdicts:  NF_ACCEPT and  NF_DROP . Is there any work around for NF_REJECT.

Comment: Can we implement the functionality of NF_REJECT, anyhow

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use NF_Drop. It should provide the functionality you are looking for.

http://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html